# Pickle a pySerial connection

Tags: python, serial-port, pickle

I'm working on a project where I want to use the same UART for several iterations, but not open and close it every time. As a result, I'm trying to use pickle to write the serial object to a file so that I can unpickle it in any file I want and not have the overhead of connecting to the serial port every time.

However, I'm running into errors. Here's my code:

```
import sys
import serial
import pickle

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty1', 19200)
f = open('myfile.dat', 'wb+')
P = pickle.Pickler(f)
lineOCode = 'LOLOLOL'
P.dump(ser)
```

---

And I'm getting error messages telling me that I can't pickle a serial object. (The port opens just fine, it's the pickle function that is having issues.)

Results:

```
File "serial_pick.py", line 9, in <module>
P.dump(ser)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
self.save(obj)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
rv = reduce(self.proto)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 80, in _reduce_ex
dict = self.__dict__
TypeError: this __dict__ descriptor does not support 'Serial' objects
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: My approach to avoid opening/closing serial ports, is writing small wrappers based on ``xmlrpclib`` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#simplexmlrpcserver-example ) and running it as a separate program - its network transparency comes in very handy.

Comment: Worth a shot. I like the idea and may look at it later tonight.

Comment: Totally works! Thanks!

Comment: Hello Dear @Dietrich. Thanks for your nice hint/idea about using xmlrpclib for data transmission over a serial connection. But could you please provide more details about how to bind the serial connection to the network ports which are used in xmlrpclib?

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can pickle such an object:

> What can you Pickle?
>
> Generally you can pickle any object if you can pickle every attribute
>   of that object. Classes, functions, and methods cannot be pickled --
>   if you pickle an object, the object's class is not pickled, just a
>   string that identifies what class it belongs to. This works fine for
>   most pickles (but note the discussion about long-term storage of
>   pickles).
>
> With pickle protocol v1, you cannot pickle open file objects, network
>   connections, or database connections. When you think about it, it
>   makes sense -- pickle cannot will the connection for file object to
>   exist when you unpickle your object, and the process of creating that
>   connection goes beyond what pickle can automatically do for you. If
>   you really want to pickle something that has an attribute that is
>   causing problems, look at the pickle documentation for **getstate**,
>   **setstate**, and **getinitargs** -- using these you can exclude problematic attributes.
>
> With pickle protocol v2, you are able to pickle open file objects.
>   This will change in a future version of Python. See this bug report
>   for more information.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the bug report?

Comment: True, with basic pickle. However, there is a section in the documentation about extending pickle for other objects. Is it possible to pickle a serial connection if I extend pickle?

Comment: Gareth, did you mean for me to link the bug report, or phoet? It's ambiguous. My bug report is in the OP.